# outgoing payment API in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, paypal, payment-gateway, payment

I am working on the project which is kind of game where user can register can give the bank detail or credit card detail and play the game and achieve the different score as per different level.

Now as per the score user get the particular amount from the admin side.
Now i need to integrate payment API in the admin panel which work like admin just have to write the amount and select submit and particular amount is been deducted from admin's account and transferred to users account.

I dont want that use will do any registeration in any kind of payment api..

Like in paypal it is possible to transfer amount from PayPal to PayPal.
but for that user and admin both must have account in paypal.

Comment: I can't wait to give my credit card details....

Comment: @MitchWheat Its a game..And there are more other feature also.. So its only only one way.. the transfer on this project will be done by both the ways.. This is the scenario for one module..